# Blazor WASM hosted in Azure Static App cannot be visited directly by using sub-directories

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM hosted on Azure Static App, website works fine. But I realized if you give someone a link to one of the pages on the site like https://www.myblazor.com/path/do, and this person never visited this site before, the site will display:

> The requested content does not exist.

```
HttpStatusCode: 404
ErrorCode: WebContentNotFound
RequestId : 18382fd7-f01e-0015-31cc-67b610000000
TimeStamp : 2021-06-23T01:10:44.3896906Z
```

The person must visit the root first https://www.myblazor.com, after the site loads, he can then manually go to the special page.

Why is this? Is it because I am using the static file service, instead of regular App Service? Is it possible to make it work? It's very common to link to a specific page on the website, not necessarily the root.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 8):

You need to configure a [fallback route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes). Add a file named `staticwebapp.config.json` in the same folder as your Blazor app's csproj file with this content:

```json
{
    "navigationFallback": {
        "rewrite": "/index.html"
    }
}
```

See this example app here: https://github.com/staticwebdev/blazor-starter/blob/main/Client/staticwebapp.config.json

Comment: In my project (.NET 7 Blazor WebAssembly) the staticwebapp.config.json should be placed into the wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error message, you might actually be using Azure Storage static website hosting, which is a different service than Azure Static Web Apps.

To set up a fallback route in Azure Storage static websites, see the "enable deep linking" section of this [blog post](https://anthonychu.ca/post/blazor-azure-storage-static-websites/).

[Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview) provides better control for this. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095350/3199781) if you want to try that. (disclaimer: I work on this service)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer from this blog:

[Blazor WASM 404 error and fix for GitHub Pages](https://blog.elmah.io/blazor-wasm-404-error-and-fix-for-github-pages/)

Although it's intended for Github pages hosting, it's the same concept as Azure Static App hosting. Works like a charm :-)

Make sure you login to your Azure portal and set the page not found setting to 404.html and save this file to your root directory, together with index.html.